# Are there any perks to being able to dual-wield the same weapon?

Tags: max-payne-3

The ability to dual-wield the same one-handed weapon seems like the most useless ability to have out of all weapon upgrades you can earn to me (golden doesn't count).  e.g., If you wanted to dual-wield two SMGs, you'd just buy two different SMGs and equip them each in a hand and you have your "dual-wield." No need to get your weapon to level 5 or 6 just to be able to do so.  Frankly I see no reason to want to use the same weapon.

Two Weapon Dual-Wielding Pros:

- You can get it as soon as you can afford it (which will be quick)
- You're leveling/grinding *both* weapons simultaneously (HUGE!)

Two Weapon Dual-Wielding Cons:

- Costs more money (is that *really* a problem?)
- Your weapons don't have the same stats (is that *really* a problem?)

---

One Weapon Dual-Wielding Pros:

- You are guaranteed upgrades for both weapons (not bad... dual high-capacity clips anyone?)
- You level/grind the weapon faster? (4-5 more levels might go quicker? I see no difference)
- You only had to get/buy one weapon saving money (again, is money really an issue?)

One Weapon Dual-Wielding Cons:

- You have to level up the weapon before you can dual-wield (if you single the gun all the way, it will take some time)

If you asked me, the pros far outweigh the cons to dual-wield two weapons.  And remember, this are single-handed weapons so you generally be shooting in close- to mid-range so differences in the weapons' stats will be unnoticeable.  Any weaknesses in one weapon will greatly be made up by the other.

I see no difference in how quickly the weapons level up.  The time it took to get a 2-handed weapon to level 10 is taking about the same time it is taking me to get two SMGs up to level 10.

**Are there any *real* benefits to dual-wielding a single weapon that you can't get with two weapons that I'm not seeing here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no particular benefits to dual-wielding the same weapon.  The level 6 unlock serves pretty much the same purpose as any other unlock:  To keep you from doing what you might otherwise do so that you have something to aim for.  Cynical way of looking at "progression," but it works.  Likewise there are no "benefits" to unlocked clothing items that would necessarily justify their not being available initially.

That said, I do tend to dual-wield the same weapon more often than not, because
1) As you said, you level a single weapon up faster instead of spreading it between two, which is nice just because you'll get the good stuff (lightweight, barrel upgrade, etc) faster.  More importantly...
2) Two weapons that behave the same way can be easier to use than two that are slightly different.  The obvious case is differing ammo capacity (try using 1911 and PT92 without extended magazine on the 1911), but even vanilla 1911 + Bull can be frustrating when one weapon's firing rate is different than the other.  In order to maximize both, you'd have to have a very strange clicking pattern.  Or in other cases, the damage dropoff may be worse on one gun versus the other.

So yeah, no strong benefit, just potentially easier to use, and another thing to unlock.

Comment: Yeah, the different ammo capacities can really hurt you at times.  Especially when you come across an enemy after killing one and you shot enough to deplete the ammo of one gun but not the other, you're then stuck with maybe 2 shots or so from one gun til you have to reload.